# Can I use javascript Google Map API without browser key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google documentation asks for browser key https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Comment: Why not just [get a key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding.

Comment: No keys needed for simple use like displaying maps on your site

Comment: @Pixel That information is no longer accurate as a result of last week changes :D

Comment: Ahh i see thanks for the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of last week (23 June, 2016 iirc), keyless usage of the Google Maps APIs was deprecated. This means that if you wish to use one of their APIs, **you need a key**.

Comment: So if i have to create an application that is going to be use widely, then my browser key load will be very high. otherwise i have to request browser key from the user itself.

Comment: You can either request a browser key, or a server key depending on your needs. As for key usage, yes, it may be high. I strongly suggest you cache results when possible, and that you throttle requests to the API. That way you will have a better control over the requests you make.